# How to fix blank space between my navigation bar and top of site?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a prototype for a portfolio I want to make for photography and my  element wont cover the entire top of the page there is a blank space above the navigation bar and I've tried multiple methods and still can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I've resetted the margin to `* {margin: 0;}` , I attempted to remove any bottom-margin space `* {bottom-margin: 0;}` , and yet it still has not worked.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("IMG_9323.jpg")
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I expect the space to be gone when I input a different method of CSS and it still stays rather than being removed.

Comment: Just ran your code, there's no white space.

Comment: It is the space of the top of the site between the navigation bar and the top.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?